# Start Tomcat from user

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, webapp2

I have one problem!
I need to start web-application in Tomcat from 'user' but Tomcat start from command line (not start as service).
I have catalina.bat file for command line:

> ```
> set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xmx1000m -Xms1000m -Xmn384m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.library.path=D:\dev\bin\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\bin
>
> rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
> set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
> if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
> set CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%
> if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
> cd ..
> set CATALINA_HOME=%cd%
> cd %CURRENT_DIR%
> :gotHome
> if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
> echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
> echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
> goto end
> :okHome
>
> rem Get standard environment variables
> if "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotSetenvHome
> if exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
> goto gotSetenvBase
> :gotSetenvHome
> if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
> :gotSetenvBase
>
> rem Get standard Java environment variables
> if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" goto okSetclasspath
> echo Cannot find %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat
> echo This file is needed to run this program
> goto end
> :okSetclasspath
> set BASEDIR=%CATALINA_HOME%
> call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" %1
> if errorlevel 1 goto end
>
> rem Add on extra jar files to CLASSPATH
> if "%JSSE_HOME%" == "" goto noJsse
> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JSSE_HOME%\lib\jcert.jar;%JSSE_HOME%\lib\jnet.jar;%JSSE_HOME%\lib\jsse.jar
> :noJsse
> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar
>
> if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
> set CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%
> :gotBase
>
> if not "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" == "" goto gotTmpdir
> set CATALINA_TMPDIR=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp
> :gotTmpdir
>
> if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" goto noJuli
> set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
> :noJuli
>
> rem ----- Execute The Requested Command ---------------------------------------
>
> echo Using CATALINA_BASE:   %CATALINA_BASE%
> echo Using CATALINA_HOME:   %CATALINA_HOME%
> echo Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: %CATALINA_TMPDIR%
> if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto use_jdk
> echo Using JRE_HOME:        %JRE_HOME%
> goto java_dir_displayed
> :use_jdk
> echo Using JAVA_HOME:       %JAVA_HOME%
> :java_dir_displayed
>
> set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
> set MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
> set ACTION=start
> set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=
> set DEBUG_OPTS=
> set JPDA=
>
> if not ""%1"" == ""jpda"" goto noJpda
> set JPDA=jpda
> if not "%JPDA_TRANSPORT%" == "" goto gotJpdaTransport
> set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_shmem
> :gotJpdaTransport
> if not "%JPDA_ADDRESS%" == "" goto gotJpdaAddress
> set JPDA_ADDRESS=jdbconn
> :gotJpdaAddress
> if not "%JPDA_SUSPEND%" == "" goto gotJpdaSuspend
> set JPDA_SUSPEND=n
> :gotJpdaSuspend
> if not "%JPDA_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJpdaOpts
> set JPDA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
> :gotJpdaOpts
> shift
> :noJpda
>
> if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto doDebug
> if ""%1"" == ""run"" goto doRun
> if ""%1"" == ""start"" goto doStart
> if ""%1"" == ""stop"" goto doStop
> if ""%1"" == ""version"" goto doVersion
>
> echo Usage:  catalina ( commands ... )
> echo commands:
> echo   debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
> echo   debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
> echo   jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
> echo   run               Start Catalina in the current window
> echo   run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
> echo   start             Start Catalina in a separate window
> echo   start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
> echo   stop              Stop Catalina
> echo   version           What version of tomcat are you running?
> goto end
>
> :doDebug
> shift
> set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJDB%
> set DEBUG_OPTS=-sourcepath "%CATALINA_HOME%\..\..\java"
> if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
> shift
> echo Using Security Manager
> set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy
> goto execCmd
>
> :doRun
> shift
> if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
> shift
> echo Using Security Manager
> set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy
> goto execCmd
>
> :doStart
> shift
> if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto noTitle
> set _EXECJAVA=start "Tomcat" %_RUNJAVA%
> goto gotTitle
> :noTitle
> set _EXECJAVA=start %_RUNJAVA%
> :gotTitle
> if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
> shift
> echo Using Security Manager
> set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy
> goto execCmd
>
> :doStop
> shift
> set ACTION=stop
> set CATALINA_OPTS=
> goto execCmd
>
> :doVersion
> %_EXECJAVA% -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
> goto end
>
>
> :execCmd
> rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the
> set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
> :setArgs
> if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
> set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
> shift
> goto setArgs
> :doneSetArgs
>
> rem Execute Java with the applicable properties
> if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
> if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
> echo  %JAVA_OPTS%
> %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
> goto end
> :doSecurity
> %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
> goto end
> :doJpda
> if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
> %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
> goto end
> :doSecurityJpda
> %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
> goto end
>
> :end
> ```

Question: How I can start Tomcat from 'user' via command line with catalina.bat ??
P.S. I have a Windows Server

Comment: Aren't you able to start the tomcat as _Tomcat Root/bin>startup.bat_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs for errors?
Best way to fix an issue is to go through the error logs.

You will find the logs directory under your tomcat install directory.
eg : tomcat_home/logs

Find the catalina.out log file and check for any errors.
If you find any errors, please post it here.

Comment: Mmm... There are no errors. I want to learn how to a specific user launch Tomcat via the command line.I mean that specific 'user' must launch my app.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned you should run Tomcat from startup.bat but you should also use [`runas` command](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html).

More or less it would look like this:

```
Runas /user:user <path>\startup.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

To start the Tomcat sever, you can write this in cmd

```
catalina start
```

Similarly, to stop the Tomcat server, you may wirte

```
catalina stop
```

Hope this helps:)